# Test if graph contains element

Tags: python, unit-testing, networkx

What I am trying to check is whether the user is part of the graph or not.

```
import graph_creator


def test_user():
    assert "user" in graph
```

Sadly, this approach results in an error:

> 'user' != <networkx.classes.multidigraph.MultiDiGraph object at 0x000002164D4567A0>
>
> Expected :<networkx.classes.multidigraph.MultiDiGraph object at 0x000002164D4567A0>
> Actual   :'user'
>
> def test_user(): assert 'user' in graph
>
> E       AssertionError: assert 'user' in <networkx.classes.multidigraph.MultiDiGraph object at 0x000002164D4567A0>

```
import graph_creator

if "user" in graph_creater.graph:
    print("true")
```

Testing like this works and returns "true".
This means that the "user" is part of my graph?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what `graph_creater` library/module is doing, but given the traceback, it might be that a specific `graph` object needs to be created. Possibly, in the snippet above, this would be `G = graph()`.

Here's an example with `networkx`:

```py
from networkx import Graph
G = Graph()

print("user" in G)
# False

print("user" in Graph)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

Comment: graph_creator just creates a networkx.MultiDiGraph() and adds nodes to this.
One of the nodes is called "user", which should be its key.

Answer (score -1):

Had to call a method within my test to add nodes to my graph.

```
import graph_creator

def test_user():
    graph_creator.create_nodes()

    assert 'user' in graph_creator.graph.nodes
```